# Paperclip change file system default storage RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm using paperclip to store and display images. I have change the default file system storage to:

```
  has_attached_file :avatar, 
                :path =>   ":rails_root/upload/:rails_env/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename", 
                styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "50x50>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png", 
                :url => "/upload/:rails_env/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename"
```

I want to store the images in the "upload" folder at the root of the application (Not in public). This part works fine.

The issue is the index and show view. I have:

```
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:thumb) %>
```

Instead of showing the ":thumb" of the image I only get the file name. I don't know why!

I know the url is correct because it does get to the right image but only the name is display.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `<%= image_tag @user.avatar(:thumb) %>`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It did not work. It shows the name of the file but it does not show the thumbnail. : (

Comment: Can you paste the generated img tag?

Comment: Hi again. Thank you for your help. I'm not sure I undrestand your request. There is no image tag generated. Only the name of the image file is shown in the index page.

Comment: What versions of Rails and Paperclip are you using?

Comment: Try removing the `:url` key of your  `has_attached_file` declaration.

Comment: Quite recent versions: Rails 4.2.1 - Paperclip 4.3

Comment: It does not work if the :url configuration is not specify. It won't find the images in the new path. That was my first mistake. According to paperclip documentation :path and :url need to be set together. Other wise it uses the default value which is in the public directory.

Comment: In many cases you needn't set the path or url arguments at all. Paperclip has pretty sensible defaults. Try removing both, get it working in development, and then work on setting your path and url if it's a hosting requirement.

Comment: I have no problem with the default settings. My issue is that it does not created the thumbnail when I modified :path and :url even though it does find the image (path is correct and it displays the name of the image).